# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01704: string literal too long When Insert Or Update

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, struct, clob

Normally when i insert 4000 character limit its works fine but when over 4000 character its throw SQL Exception string literal too long even my DISCHARGE_TEXT data type is CLOB

**My JavaScript code is**

```
function saveAsDraftNew(){
    var admissionNo = document.getElementById("apnNo").value;
    if (admissionNo == "") {
        alert("Please Insert Admission Number");
        berak;
    } else {
        var idval = "";
        var regNo = document.getElementById("regNo").innerHTML;
        var editorValue = document.getElementById("editor").value;
        //alert(editorValue.length);
        alert(editorValue);
        editorValuee = unescape(editorValue);
        //alert(editorValuee.length);
        //alert(editorValuee);
        var referredTo = document.getElementById("otherAnswer").value = "";
        var modeOfDischarge = document.getElementsByName('answer');
        for ( var i = 0; i < modeOfDischarge.length; i++) {
            if (modeOfDischarge[i].checked) {
                var rate_value = modeOfDischarge[i].value;


                    $jf.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:"saveEditorValueAsTemplateIPDPatientInfo.do",
                                data:{
                                    patientAdmissionNo:admissionNo,
                                    editorValueM:editorValuee,
                                    btnYesM:idval,
                                    regNoM:regNo,
                                    referredToM:referredTo,
                                    rate_valueM:rate_value,
                                },
                                success : function(result) {
                                    $jf("#btndiv").html(result);
                                },
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Action Class Code is**

```
private String patientAdmissionNo = null;
Date date;
String regNoM;
String btnYesM = "";
String editorValueM = "";
String referredToM = "";
String rate_valueM;

public String saveEditorValueAsTemplate() {
    String[] logInInfo = (String[]) ActionContext.getContext().getSession()
            .get(sessionVariable.getUserLogInInfo());
    String specialization_no = logInInfo[12];
    int specializationInt = specialization_no == null
            || specialization_no.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer
            .parseInt(specialization_no);
    String doctorEmpId = logInInfo[1].toString();
    String companyNo = logInInfo[4].toString();

    Long rowInserted = patientTreatmentOfDischargeSql
            .addPatientDischargeValue(btnYesM, editorValueM,
                    patientAdmissionNo, regNoM, specializationInt,
                    doctorEmpId, companyNo, doctorEmpId, date, rate_valueM,
                    referredToM);

    if (btnYesM.equals("0") || btnYesM.equals("1")) {
        deschargeInfo.setBtnSave(false);
        deschargeInfo.setBtnSaveAsDruft(false);
        deschargeInfo.setBtnResumeOnDraft(false);
    } else {

        deschargeInfo.setBtnSave(false);
        deschargeInfo.setBtnSaveAsDruft(false);
        deschargeInfo.setBtnResumeOnDraft(true);
    }
    return "saveEditorValueAsTemplate";
}
```

**My SQL Code is**

```
public Long addPatientDischargeValue(String CRITICAL_FLAG , String DISCHARGE_TEXT ,String ADMISSION_NO , String REG_NO ,Integer specialization_no,String ENTERED_BY, String COMPANY_NO, String UPDATE_BY, Date UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,String mode_of_discharge, String referred_to) {
    Long rowInserted=(long) 0;

    boolean fg = true;
    con = dbc.connectDB();

    if (con == null) {
        fg = false;
    }
    if (fg) {
        try {
            st = con.createStatement();
            String countQry = "SELECT COUNT(ADMISSION_NO) COUNT FROM IP_DISCHARGE WHERE ADMISSION_NO='"
                    + ADMISSION_NO + "'";

            int countNo= 0;
            ResultSet rsCount=st.executeQuery(countQry);
            if(rsCount.next()){
                countNo = rsCount.getInt("COUNT");
            }

            String insertUpdate = null;

            if (countNo > 0) {

                insertUpdate="update ip_discharge set " +
                        " update_by    ='"+UPDATE_BY+"', " +
                        " updated_timestamp      = sysdate, " +                             
                        "  critical_flag  = '" + CRITICAL_FLAG + "' ," +
                        "  discharge_text = '" + DISCHARGE_TEXT + "', " +
                        "  mode_of_discharge = '" + mode_of_discharge + "', " +
                        "  referred_to       = '" + referred_to + "' " +
                        " where " +
                        " admission_no = '"+ ADMISSION_NO+ "'";


            } else {
                String PK_NO = generatedSequence("",
                        "SEQ_PATTYPEDTL", "D", "1", "Y");
                insertUpdate = "INSERT INTO ip_discharge (DISCHARGE_ID,ADMISSION_NO , reg_no, DISCHARGE_TEXT , specialization_no , CRITICAL_FLAG , ENTERED_BY , COMPANY_NO, mode_of_discharge, referred_to "
                        + ")values('"+ PK_NO+ "','"+ ADMISSION_NO+ "','"+ REG_NO+ "','" + DISCHARGE_TEXT + "'," + specialization_no + ",'" + CRITICAL_FLAG + "','" + ENTERED_BY + "','" + COMPANY_NO + "','" + mode_of_discharge + "','" + referred_to + "')";
            }
            System.out.println(insertUpdate);
            st.executeUpdate(insertUpdate);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                st.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return rowInserted;
}
```

**my table data Type is**

```
CREATE TABLE IP_DISCHARGE
(
  DISCHARGE_ID       VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  ADMISSION_NO       VARCHAR2(16 BYTE)          NOT NULL,
  ENTERED_BY         VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  ENTRY_TIMESTAMP    DATE                       DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  UPDATE_BY          VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  UPDATED_TIMESTAMP  DATE,
  COMPANY_NO         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  DEPT_NO            NUMBER,
  CRITICAL_FLAG      VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  DISCHARGE_TEXT     CLOB,
  REG_NO             VARCHAR2(22 BYTE),
  MODE_OF_DISCHARGE  VARCHAR2(22 BYTE),
  REFERRED_TO        VARCHAR2(22 BYTE),
  SPECIALIZATION_NO  NUMBER
)
```

Comment: SQL injections welcome. Seriously: Don't concatenate variables into SQL statements. It will considerably worsen your performance, and it's an invitation for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because your SQL statement (which is the result of this statement:

```
 insertUpdate = "INSERT INTO ip_discharge (DISCHARGE_ID,ADMISSION_NO , reg_no, DISCHARGE_TEXT , specialization_no , CRITICAL_FLAG , ENTERED_BY , COMPANY_NO, mode_of_discharge, referred_to "
                        + ")values('"+ PK_NO+ "','"+ ADMISSION_NO+ "','"+ REG_NO+ "','" + DISCHARGE_TEXT + "'," + specialization_no + ",'" + CRITICAL_FLAG + "','" + ENTERED_BY + "','" + COMPANY_NO + "','" + mode_of_discharge + "','" + referred_to + "')";
            }
```

is getting too long.

Building your SQL statement in this way (by concatenating variable values together) is a very bad idea because

- it negatively impacts performance (you force the database to parse a
  new statement every time)
- it allows SQL injection attacks
- it limits the amount of data you can insert because your SQL statement must not exceed 4000 characters in length

Solution: use a Prepared Statement with bind variables instead

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear MR Frank Schmitt i just solved this problem for flow your advice

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL editor run update or insert query by putting static value and check are yo getting error there.

Comment: In editor Toad i put the Static value and got the same error. only 4000 characters allow over 4000 characters its says string literal too long....

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify  DISCHARGE_TEXT CLOB(64 K) or something like as per your requirement.
See this defination.

**CLOB data type**

A CLOB (character large object) value can be up to 2,147,483,647 characters long. A CLOB is used to store unicode character-based data, such as large documents in any character set.

The length is given in number characters for both CLOB, unless one of the suffixes K, M, or G is given, relating to the multiples of 1024, 1024*1024, 1024*1024*1024 respectively.

Length is specified in characters (unicode) for CLOB.

Comment: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 8
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

i just solve this problem to change SQL Statement to Prepared Statement

**here is my new sql code**

public Long addPatientDischargeValue(String CRITICAL_FLAG , String DISCHARGE_TEXT ,String ADMISSION_NO , String REG_NO ,Integer specialization_no,String ENTERED_BY, String COMPANY_NO, String UPDATE_BY, Date UPDATED_TIMESTAMP,String mode_of_discharge, String referred_to) {
            Long rowInserted=(long) 0;

```
        boolean fg = true;
        con = dbc.connectDB();

        if (con == null) {
            fg = false;
        }
        if (fg) {
            try {
                Date today = new Date();
                st = con.createStatement();
                String countQry = "SELECT COUNT(ADMISSION_NO) COUNT FROM IP_DISCHARGE WHERE ADMISSION_NO='"
                        + ADMISSION_NO + "'";

                int countNo= 0;
                ResultSet rsCount=st.executeQuery(countQry);
                if(rsCount.next()){
                    countNo = rsCount.getInt("COUNT");
                }

                String insertUpdate = null;
                String Pk_No="";
                if (countNo > 0) {

                insertUpdate=   "update ip_discharge set  " +
                    "update_by = ?,  " +
                    "updated_timestamp = ? , " +
                    "critical_flag = ? , " +
                    "discharge_text = ?,  " +
                    "mode_of_discharge = ? , " +
                    "referred_to = ?  " +
                    "where  admission_no = ?  ";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertUpdate);

                preparedStatement.setString(1, UPDATE_BY);
                preparedStatement.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(today.getTime()));
                preparedStatement.setString(3, CRITICAL_FLAG);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, DISCHARGE_TEXT);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, mode_of_discharge);
                preparedStatement.setString(6, "referred_to");
                preparedStatement.setString(7, ADMISSION_NO);

                    // execute update SQL stetement
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


                } else {
                    Pk_No = generatedSequence("","SEQ_PATTYPEDTL", "D", "1", "Y");
                    insertUpdate = "INSERT INTO ip_discharge (DISCHARGE_ID,ADMISSION_NO , reg_no, DISCHARGE_TEXT , specialization_no , CRITICAL_FLAG , ENTERED_BY , COMPANY_NO, mode_of_discharge, referred_to "
                            + ")values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(insertUpdate);

                preparedStatement.setString(1, Pk_No);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, ADMISSION_NO);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, REG_NO);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, DISCHARGE_TEXT);
                preparedStatement.setInt(5, specialization_no);
                preparedStatement.setString(6, CRITICAL_FLAG);
                preparedStatement.setString(7, ENTERED_BY);
                preparedStatement.setString(8, COMPANY_NO);
                preparedStatement.setString(9, mode_of_discharge);
                preparedStatement.setString(10, referred_to);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println(insertUpdate);
            }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    st.close();
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return rowInserted;
    }
```